# How do I model tight corners without getting pinched geometry?

Tags: modeling, topology

Anyone know how to model a curved surface with tight, rounded corners without getting the pinching like I am in the images below?

[Blender File Link To Examine](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V7syt0XSwnEbiRI32oB4RmJ-3oLjNnvL/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to add more topology, see the before and after, in *Edit* mode and in *Object* mode. Sometimes use *Vertices > Smooth Vertices* or right click > *LoopTools > Relax* in order to smooth the edge loops:

[image]

[image]